# Can you INNER JOIN in SQL 2 tables by multiple columns?

Tags: sql

I have 2 tables, with this structure:

acounts:

```
accountID | accountName | balance
```

transfer:

```
transferID | wherefrom | whereto | amount | time
```

I'd like to make a SELECT where both the wherefrom and whereto is connected to the accountID filed.

I tried something like this, but didn't work:

```
SELECT * FROM 
(
 (
   transfer 
   INNER JOIN accounts ON transfer.wherefrom = accounts.accountID
 ) 
 INNER JOIN accounts ON transfer.whereto = accounts.accountID
) 
ORDER BY time DESC;
```

Comment: Please explain "but didn't work".  (If only for future readers of this question....)  and, please, add some example data of input, and expected output.

Comment: Use single `JOIN` with `AND` in its `ON` clause. Assuming you want the two conditions to be satisfied on the **same** row, or `OR` otherwise.

Comment: No need for those parentheses.

Comment: `time` is a SQL reserved word (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_reserved_words,) might need to be delimited as `"time"`. (At least for some dbms's.)

Comment: @jarlh: some DBMS (like MySQL) consider a word delimited with double quotes a text field, and sorting on a fixed text field makes no sense...

Comment: @Luuk, yes, I know. MySQL is a bit odd, but isn't there a setting to use double quotes? Anyway, MySQL doesn't have time as reserved, so no need to delimit it in that case. (Besides, the <sql> tag says "_Answers to questions tagged with SQL should use ISO/IEC standard SQL._".)

Comment: Each account instance should have its own alias, like `... INNER JOIN accounts a1 ON transfer.wherefrom = a1.accountID ...`.

Comment: see: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html#keywords-8-0-detailed-T to find "TIME" in the list 

Comment: @PM77-1 This is very helpful, thank you. 

Unfortunately I need the AND version, because I will make a table in php, where the wherefrom and whereto will be displayed as the name of the accounts but it doesn't give back any rows. With OR it gives back 2, but that won't work for me.

Comment: @Luuk, yes, it's a MySQL keyword, but not reserved. (No R next to it.)

Comment: @jarlh With aliases it works great, but I cannot differentiate by the account names, since both columns are called the same.

Comment: It is still unclear what you are trying to achieve. Please add sufficient sample data and the desired result.

Comment: You can chose different column aliases as well, like `select a1.accountName  as fromaccountName, ...`

Comment: In the end, my goal is to display each transaction in a table like this: 

`| transferID | wherefrom | whereto | amount |---------->
| 1             | Card          | Cash     | 1000     |`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 select t.transferID "transferID", a1.accountName "wherefrom", a2.accountName "whereto", t.amount "amount"
   from transfer t
         inner join account a1 on a1.accountId = t.wherefrom
         inner join account a2 on a2.accountId = t.whereto
  order by t.time desc;
```

Comment: Just how I imagined! Thank you so much!